# When to use static and class methods

Tags: python, python-2.7, methods, maya

I know there is a lot of topics on this subject, and I've looked at many. However it is still confusing to me when its appropriate to use static and class methods in place of an instance method.

In my example, I'm making a script for the autodesk program maya. One of my modules has a class in it with methods that will generate an object in it, like below:

```
class Curves(object):
    """Contains methods to generate curves
    """
    @classmethod
    def circle_crv(cls):
        name = mc.circle( nr=(0, 1, 0), c=(0, 0, 0), r=0.5 )
        mc.delete(name, ch=True)
        mc.addAttr(name[0], ln='crvType', dt='string', h=True)
        mc.setAttr(name[0]+'.crvType', 'circle_crv', typ='string', l=True)
        return name[0]
```

However these will never be directly accessed by an external module. I run all of these methods through a dictionary thats accessed by an external modules (which first searches through an external user dictionary), which is below:

```
def curve_lib(self, crvtype):
        """Creates a specified curve at origin

        Args:
        crvtype (str): a key to call a function to generate a curve at the
            origin
        """
        userlib = self.usercurve_lib()

        curves_dic = {
            'bendjoint_crv' : self.bendjoint_crv,
            'circle_crv' : self.circle_crv,
            'circlearrow_crv' : self.circlearrow_crv,
            'connectjoint_crv' : self.connectjoint_crv,
            'fktext_crv' : self.fktext_crv,
            'joint_crv' : self.joint_crv,
            'iktext_crv' : self.iktext_crv,
            'cube_crv' : self.cube_crv,
            'quadarrow01_crv' : self.quadarrow01_crv,
            'quadarrow02_crv' : self.quadarrow02_crv,
            'quadarrow03_crv' : self.quadarrow03_crv,
            'quadarrow04_crv' : self.quadarrow04_crv,
            'rootjoint_crv' : self.rootjoint_crv,
            'square_crv' : self.square_crv,
            'switch_crv' : self.switch_crv,
            'triangle_crv' : self.triangle_crv
        }

        if crvtype in userlib:
            name = self.usercurve_lib(crvtype)
        elif crvtype in curves_dic:
            name = curves_dic[crvtype]()
        else:
           raise NameError('Key "%s" not found' %(crvtype))
        return name
```

So first question, if the method is never accessed from outside of the class or module, does it need to be an instance? And would a static or class method be appropriate in this case, since in this case I dont need seperate instances of this, it just does one thing, and never changes the size or shape, thats resized later.

Next, if i have a method in a class that just performs a simple calculation like below, would a static method be appropriate? Since its just taking input and outputting a single thing every time, is there any reason for it to be an instance?:

```
class Vectors(object):
    """Contains methods for various vector math functions
    """

    @staticmethod
    def pointLineDist(vec_a, vec_b, vec_c):
        """The distance between the line ab and the point c.

        Args:
        vec_a (float list): First vector to find distance of.
        vec_b (float list): Second vector to find distance of.
        vec_c (float list): Third vector to find distance of.
        """
        ab = dt.Vector(vec_b) - dt.Vector(vec_a)
        ac = dt.Vector(vec_c) - dt.Vector(vec_a)
        length = dt.length(dt.cross(ab, ac)) / dt.length(ab)

        return length
```

Lastly, I know a lot of people say in these cases, these shouldn't be in the class at all, or something like that, but this is the way I want it, I just want to know more in depth when to use these types of methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put it simply, an instance is an entity, a class is the concept of the entity. For instance, if you have a class Human, then an instance is a human being, while the Human class corresponds to the concept of humanity. For instance, it is pointless to measure the level of pollution generated by a person. Measuring the pollution caused by humanity makes more sense. So, if you have a method called measureGeneratedPollution, it should be static. However, if you have a method called breath, then it is natural that this is an individual action, so breath should be an instance-level method. Instance-level versus static-level is essentially analogous to individual action versus collective action.

Let's see another example for members. Let's consider the class Bird. The birds, collectively do not have a color, so color should be instance-level member. However, birdCount is a collective information, therefore it should be static.

Remember that for members/methods the level (instance or class level) is not determined by the accessibility, but by the subject behind having the attribute or doing the action. So, if we translate this into sentence-logic, then you should write down sentences to yourself while you are making such plans until you get more professional. Sentences, like:

> The bird has a color.
>
> There is a number of birds.

Ask questions to yourself:

> Who has a color? -> the bird -> singular -> instance Who have the
>
> number? -> the birds -> plural -> collective -> static

Comment: Thats very helpful! However, is class method vs instance determined by accessibility? Like say I have a bird class with a color method, but this method is only used within the class by another instance method. Would this make more sense to be a class method?

Comment: No, this is not how we should put it. The real question is: is the method individual, or is it collective. Example: A Human instance has a method for sex(). sex() is not a collective action (at least, hopefully) and the person's sex method is private, as the other Human instances should not be able to invoke the sex() method of the current individual. So, sex() is private and instance-level. So the question is not the publicity-level, but the individual or collective nature of the method/member.